# Entity framework returns entity which doesn't exist in database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I got a very strange behavior with EF6. I have an entity which insertion failed, but when i enumerate the entities, the first time after that, I retrieve the entity

```
static async Task Debug()
{
    MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();
    Category category = new Category()
    {              
        Name = "TEST INSERTION FAILED",
        Reference = "KKK",
        TranslationCategories = new List<TranslationCategory>()
        {
            new TranslationCategory()
            {                        
                //LangId = "FR", Force insertion failed
                Name= "FR translation"
            }
        }
    };
    try
    {
        ctx.Categories.Add(category);
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        // throw exception because "LangId" missing in Translation Category
    }
    MyDbContext ctx2 = new MyDbContext();
    foreach(var o in ctx2.Categories.ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o.Name);
        //output : "TEST INSERTION FAILED" + categories stored in DB
        // Why category "TEST INSERTION FAILED" in ctx2.Categories ?
    }
    Console.WriteLine("****************");
    foreach (var o in ctx2.Categories.ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o.Name);
        // ouput : only categories stored in DB
    }
}
```

Category entity generated by entity framework power tools

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new List<Product>();            
        this.TranslationCategories = new List<TranslationCategory>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Published { get; set; }
    public string Artwork { get; set; }
    public string TypeCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<TranslationCategory> TranslationCategories {get;set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the category and db class?

Comment: what if you use `SaveChanges` instead of `SaveChangesAsync`?

Comment: @Hopless already try, and same strange behavior.

Comment: @AlexKrups Category is just an entity, and MyDbContext a DBContext with DBSet<Category>

Comment: I Get that but it looks like your entity has references to other entities (TranslationCategory) which if that's the case EF will need references to those entity objects and their refrences

Comment: Have you reviewed your database to make sure there wasn't accidentally a record successfully inserted with that Name previously?

Comment: Yes i have. There is only one record.

Comment: I'm the only one having this bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. My entities and DBContext was generated using "entity framework power tools, reverse engineer code first". 
I have regenerated entities and dbcontext by adding Ado.net data entity model, Code First from Existing Database, and now the same code works.